# NW.js 16 won't show script in the sources tab

Tags: javascript, devtools, nw.js, nwjs

So I recently updated to the newest version of NW.js *(nwjs-sdk-v0.16.1-linux-x64)* and tried to port my current project over to it. Attempting to debug some of the script (a library I called "bunny.js") I noticed that my code will be shown under "Applications" but not in the sources tab like I am used to. This would be fine if I could debug from the applications tab, but apparently it's just a monitor of sorts not actually meant for interaction. A picture (blurred code because it's not finished yet):

[image]

Is this just a new NW.js thing? I feel like I am either missing something obvious. If someone knows, please let me know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to manually refresh the page with a console command to make my scripts show up properly. NWJS should give you a "refresh" button in the context menu below the "reload" option. >:-(